# Should I calculate Cronbach's alpha for a linear regression model?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, linear, psychometrics, validity

I'm interested in modelling a trait Y using variables X1, X2, X3.

I'm using a linear regression model to predict trait Y using the independent variables and therefore want to avoid multicollinearity in my model.

However, in order to test internal validity I might wish to calculate Cronbach's alpha which gives a good value precisely when X1, X2 and X3 are correlated.

This seems to be contradictory. To have a valid linear regression model I want to avoid variable correlations, but for the "test" to be reliable they should be correlated.

Should I calculate Cronbach's alpha, or is there a more suitable measure for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

As you can assume, this relationship could be bi-directional. Y could be reflected in X1, X2 and X3. An example, wealth may be a latent trait that is reflected in the number of jets one has, number of glamour spouses, ... In this scenario, you could use Cronbach's $\alpha$. Note that Cronbach's $\alpha$ [can be problematic for testing even the things we claim it is supposed to test](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11336-008-9101-0), talk less of internal validity - which it does not test.

However, if you can have a sense of Y by combining observed variables i.e. they sum up to Y, not that Y is reflected in them, then you could regress Y on X1, X2 and X3, or simply even add them up. In this situation, you would not test whether X1, X2 and X3 are "reliable" items on a scale measuring Y because they are measuring different things.

I'm guessing your case is more the second scenario, than the first.